# Android Database in app space or sdcard

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

I am working on an Android App that will have a database. I am sure that the database will grow big. Is it a good idea to create the database in the App Space or sdcard, especially when you know that it will grow big ?

Are there any security concerns if we use sdcard for the database ?

Comment: How Large? What's in the database? How fast does it need to be? Could it be rebuilt if needed?

Comment: Its getting data over Bluetooth very frequently from different sensors and data would remain in the database for 2 days. For example, there could be an instance where the app is getting data at a speed of 3 records per second or 2 records in 5 seconds. So, its quite fast.

Comment: It the database is lost once, then there's no way I can rebuild.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the app space. Even if it will grow bigger. Use the app space.

on SD-Card your database can:

- be deleted by the user
- be deleted by applications with WRITE_STORAGE access
- be physically removed from the device (removing the SD-card)
- be read/write by everyone (including other developers and users).
- it can be read/write by the user by removing the SD-card and connecting it to his computer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Budius